# How can I have my website come up on a google search with not only the name & address but with the map and red marker?

Tags: google-maps, search, marker, street-address

We are Culinary institute of Bologna CIBO at. Via Augusto Righi 30b bologna italy 40126.  If for example you google o bologna cooking school another school with map comes up ....but my place never does. How can I gret the map and the marker to show up in a google search?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this cannot directly be enabled and appears when Google rank you highly enough. You can however help yourself by providing the address on your website and by getting setup with Google Webmaster Tools. Check out the Video under Optimization > Structured data from within your site under webmaster tools. Also get setup under Google Places again from Webmaster tools.

Answer (score 0):

you must put your business on google maps

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lbc&passive=1209600&continue=http://www.google.com/local/add/businessCenter?hl%3Den%26gl%3Dus&followup=http://www.google.com/local/add/businessCenter?hl%3Den%26gl%3Dus&hl=en

they will then ask for address confirmation(they mail you an postcard) and phone confirmation

this will show your place if they search for your location, however this as that is considered an associative search and may not show up for other keywords